# User created categories for followed users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I implemented the Twitter-like blog in Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial.  I now want to add my own features to further understand Rails.  I have users following others through the Relationship model.  Now I want to give users the ability to sort the people they are following by creating custom Category model - That is, I could create personal custom categories for friends, family, etc. and place the people I'm following in the correct group.

The way I have thought about implementing this is by creating a Category model and implementing the association through an intermediary model similar to Relationship such as CategoryList.  Therefore, each Category will has_many Following through CategoryList.  Is the most effective / Rails way to handle the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a model category that is simply the list of all of the categories.  Then you should have a category_relationship join table that represents all of the entries.  So a relationship has many categories through category_relationship. At least that is how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the best way to do it as well.  I'll implement and see how it goes.